# WooCommerce custom quantity input step for each cart item based on custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product-quantity

I am using `woocommerce_quantity_input_args` hook in PHP snippet, I've got a number saved in metadata for each product and I want to apply that metadata to `$args['step']` for each quantity step in cart as they aren't all the same.

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'woocommerceQuantityInputArgs', 10, 2);
function woocommerceQuantityInputArgs( $args, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
        $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $args['step'] = $product->get_meta('_quantity_product_in_package');
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried saving all the meta data in a seperate array and loop through it and apply it to $args, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your current code, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'cart_item_quantity_input_step', 100, 2);
function cart_item_quantity_input_step( $input_args, $product ) {
    $input_args['step'] = $product->get_meta('_quantity_product_in_package');

    return $input_args;
}
```

To limit that only on cart page, use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'cart_item_quantity_input_step', 100, 2);
function cart_item_quantity_input_step( $input_args, $product ) {
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        $input_args['step'] = $product->get_meta('_quantity_product_in_package');
    }
    return $input_args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.